# MS Access parameterized queries VB

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO Log " _
  & "(UserName, DateAccessed) VALUES " _
  & "(@GetLogonName, @Today);"
```

GetLogonName and Today are variables but I get error "error- too few parameters, expected two". If I run the function using actual values like &"('abce', '2/2/2012') it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code where you pass the parameters values. If you never pass the parameters values, so you already know where is the problem.

Comment: Can you do this kind of variable substitution in VBA? I think you may need to concatenate them in ("&GetLogonName&","&Today&").

Comment: @ScottHarris This isn't a substitution, this is a parameterized query. They are used to avoid concatenation, the SQL injection attacks it allows and the performance hit it incurs

Comment: I think Database.Execute doesn't support parameters, you need to use QueryDef for this

Comment: @PaulFrancis If we are talking about DAO, [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654(v=office.14).aspx) suggests you can only pass an `Options` parameter to Database.Execute

Answer (score 3):

[Database.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654(v=office.15).aspx) doesn't accept query parameters, only the execution options defined in [RecordsetOptionEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192649(v=office.15).aspx).

To run a parameterized query you need to create a [QueryDef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn123782(v=office.15).aspx) object:

```
Dim query As QueryDef
Set query = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", "INSERT INTO LOG (UserName,DateAccessed)" & _
                                         " VALUES(@user,@time)")
query.Parameters("@user").Value = "Moo"
query.Parameters("@time").Value = Now
query.Execute
```

The empty string means this is a temporary QueryDef. If you enter any other name, or omit the name entirely, a new Query object will be created in the database.

If you use the same query frequently, it's a good idea to create a Query and call it by name:

```
Set query = dbs.QueryDefs("myQueryName")
...
```

[QueryDef.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821728(v=office.15).aspx) accepts the same execution parameters as Database.Execute

Comment: String concatenation isn't the same as passing parameters to a query - it's actually the opposite. Even if Access creates a new execution plan for every parameterized query, the penalty will be identical to executing a raw statement. If it caches plans though, you *avoid* recompilation. Plus, you avoid type conversions and injections. String concatenation is a very expensive habit, which is why it's frowned upon